# Get the index of a string from a string array based on the first occurrence of a string being a part of it

Tags: javascript

I have an array and string

```
const arr = ['home', 'about', 'contact']
const value = 'desktop_about'
const priority = ?
```

The priority should be 1 as thats the index of the first string to included in itself, partly or fully.

What would be the best way to calculate this, I thought about different loops but all seemed overcomplicated

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
const priority = arr.findIndex(v => value.includes(v));
```